# Hide CSP nonce in browser console

Tags: javascript, php, content-security-policy

I add CSP header to my project. Browser now doesnot load the script that doesnot include the nonce, great. But in the console error it display my nonce. Is this by design?
here is how I add my content header in php side

`header("Content-Security-Policy: script-src 'nonce-$nonce' 'self' ")`

here is how I load my script

`echo'<script nonce='.$nonce.' type="text/javascript" src="file.js"></script>'`

But browser throw error when I try to load script where nonce is not declared plus display my nonce as in the attachment(Although I recreate new nonce on every page reload it doesenot feel right). is this by design?
[image]

Comment: What makes you think this was a problem?

Comment: I am not sure. I am just thinking if it create issue  as script with the nonce can be loaded.

Comment: Yes, it's "by design". Knowing the `nonce` after the page is loaded into the browser will not give anything to the attacker. On next page load, the `nonce` will be different, so it XSS injection will be impossible.